# How to implement fractionally strided convolution layers in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, convolution, generative-adversarial-network, deconvolution

Before everything, I searched google and StackOverflow but I do not find any similar questions so here I propose a new one.

I'm interested in  [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.08207) and want to implement this SGAN for my project. The paper mentioned that its generator network is composed of "a stack of fractionally strided convolution layers", I found two different ways of implementing this in pytorch, one is:

```py
torch.nn.Sequential(
    # other layers...
    torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(),
    # other layers...
)
```

the other way is:

```py
torch.nn.Sequential(
    # other layers...
    torch.nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2),
    torch.nn.Conv2D(),
    # other layers...
)
```

So, my question is, which is the better implementation of fractionally strided conv layer, or am I understanding something completely wrong?

Thanks in advance.

P.S, I found the second implementation [here](https://github.com/zalandoresearch/famos/blob/master/network.py), in line 87 - 88.

Comment: It would be better to ask this question at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Don't know Code Review before, will do it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tldr; There are some shape constraints but both perform the same operations.**

---

The output shape of [`nn.ConvTranspose2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d.html) is given by `y = (x − 1)s - 2p + d(k-1) + p_out + 1`, where `x` and `y` are the input and ouput shape, respectively, `k` is the kernel size, `s` the stride, `d` the dilation, `p` and `p_out` the padding and padding out. Here we keep things simple with `s=1`, `p=0`, `p_out=0`, `d=1`.

Therefore, the output shape of the transposed convolution is:

```
y =  x - 1 + k
```

If we look at an upsample (x2) with convolution. Using the same notation as before, the output of [`nn.Conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) is given by: `y = floor((x + 2p - d(k - 1) - 1) / s + 1)`. After [upsampling](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Upsample.html) `x` is sized `2x`. We keep the dilation at `d=1`.

```
y = floor((2x + 2p - k) / s + 1)
```

If we want to match the output shape of the transposed convolution, we need to have `x - 1 + k = floor((2x + 2p - k) / s + 1)`. This relation will define the values to choose for `s` and `p` for our convolution.

Taking a simple example for demonstration: `k=2`. Now `x + 1` needs to be equal to `floor((2x + 2p - k) / s + 1)`, which is solved by setting `s=2` and `p=1`.

---

Here is the same example in a visual form.

[image]

- transposed convolution

[image]

- upsample + convolution

[image]

Comment: Great visualizations! Though why was the kernel "flipped" in the transposed convolution? I believe it's the same kernel, but it differs in the way it behaves/operates as seen in these animations: https://github.com/aqeelanwar/conv_layers_animation. I also tried recreating your example using the same inputs and kernel weights and the outputs were indeed different.